# UISearchController.searchBar as tableHeaderView causing a blank UIView on the top of a UITableView when pulling down

Tags: uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have been using `UISearchController.searchBar` as `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView`, when I pull down the tableView, a strange blank `UIView` will be inserted at the top of my tableView. This strange view always has a light gray backgroundColor even if dark mode is turned on:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3T2a.png)

But when I set a normal UIView as the tableHeaderView, everything is fine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2m6z.png)

In the Debug View Hierarchy, the UIView is inserted before any cell and after the searchBar:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSLSV.jpg)

But when I'm not pulling down the UITableView, the UIView will vanish from the view hierarchy.

Below is the code I run:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    let normalHeaderView = UIView()
    let searchController = UISearchController()

    let items: [String] = [
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4",
        "Item 5",
        "Item 6",
        "Item 7"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.height.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        
//        normalHeaderView.backgroundColor = .red
//        tableView.tableHeaderView = normalHeaderView
//        normalHeaderView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
//            make.width.equalToSuperview()
//            make.height.equalTo(50)
//        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an odd side effect, the workaround I found is to create a view with desired color and specify it as the tableView's backgroundView